# Ebean: delete with Query object

Tags: ebean

Suppose I have a `com.avaje.ebean.Query` type object, is there any way for me to use it as `where` clause to delete entities in the table? I was trying to look for something like `EbeanServer.delete(Query)` but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you'd do this using `EbeanServer.createUpdate(...)`.  So Update can process bulk update or delete statements.

The limitation to using Update is that it does not currently have the same criteria/expressionList support that Query does. This issue is logged as: https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/issues/120

Comment: I've submitted another one: https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/issues/398

Answer (score 0):

```
   SomeModel.find
      .where()
      .eq("someProperty", property)
      .delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
query = Ebean.createQuery(Device.class);
query.where().conjunction()
                .lt("last_update", new LocalDate().minusDays(250))
                .eq("appname", "XXXX")
             .endJunction();

List<Device> devices = query.findList();

for( Device d : devices ) {
    d.delete();
}
```